# Cannot connect html to css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to run my html file but it doesn't know where the css file is .I have two files index.html and style.css both on my desktop.Here how my index.html file looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>

  <section class="header">
    // lots of info here
  </section>
```

and my css has all the things needed.

but the html doesn't get connected to the css file

here is how a part of  my style.css look like :

```
  .user {

& {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

i {
  font-size: $large;

  &:hover {
    color: $white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

&__notifications {}

&__inbox {}

 ...
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `<body>` element. More importantly though, are you sure the path to the stylesheet is correct, and that the syntax you've used is valid?

Comment: unless you give a full path, it always looks at the path relative to where the html file itself is located. So if the css file is right next to the html, simply write href="style.css"

Comment: What does your CSS code look like?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan should the <body> be around <selection> because I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Yes it should. Although it won't affect the issue you're having as a browser will fix the issue for you. You should really make sure your HTML meets standards, though as you can run in to major issues otherwise

Comment: Also note the 'CSS' you've added to the question looks a lot like a SCSS/SASS/LESS stylesheet. You need to run it through a pre-processor. Currently it is not valid CSS, hence the browser ignores it

Comment: If JavaScript and jQuery are relevant here, show the relevant code. If not, don’t use those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrap your `<section>` as well as other html elements after your `<head>` tag within `<body>` tags.
2. Recompile the `scss` code to `css`.

Comment: Only point 3 is actually needed. If the html and css files are in the same directory, then the OP's `./styles.css` would also work. So the only problem was the uncompiled SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the same directory, you should be using `style.css` as your `href` (without any leading slashes or dots). And don't forget to close your `<body>` and `<html>` tags at the end.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <section class="header">
    //lots of info here
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, it looks like your CSS is actually written in a preprocessing language (possibly SCSS). You should remove all of the variables (`$...`) and flatten all of the nested selectors (`&`).

```css
.user {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.user i {
  font-size: 10em; /* or whatever $large was */
}

.user i:hover {
  color: #fff; /* or whatever $white was */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.user__notifications {}

.user__inbox {}
```

Comment: tried it like that again it doesn't detect the css.I copied the css from here https://codepen.io/alowenthal/pen/rxboRv and the selection class is the same as the HTML

Comment: See my edit. The CSS is written in SCSS (a preprocessing language that doesn't directly run in the browser).

Comment: On Codepen you can click the down arrow under CSS and then hit "View Compiled CSS" to see the final styles.

Comment: on codepen press `v arrow` and `view compiled css` in `css` section, otherwise you will not run it directly from browser, because as @gyre said it is preprocessing language.

Comment: SOlved:I needed view compiled css and it ran :)